# Unexpected output when using exponent operator(**) with float value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponentiation

I am currently using Python 3.6 in Windows 7.

When I use exponent operator(**) with float that gives a large number, I get an unexpected output.

For example, the output of "10^32" differs whether the exponent is in a form of an integer(32) or a float(32.0).

```
   >>>print (int(10**(32.0)))
   100000000000000005366162204393472

   >>>print (int(10**(32)))
   100000000000000000000000000000000
```

[Using "**"operator in Python(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8YCR.jpg)

Is there a reason for the different output?

If so, how can i fix the problem?

Comment: same comes out to be in `python 3.3` / `centos-6` ... guess it has nothing to do with OS! :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2823755)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems the problem is more complicated than I expected:(

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the inherent inaccuracy of floating point representation. See [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).